# jQuery combining URL using a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, url

When uploaded to a hosted server the following code is successfully turned to `http://myexample.com/otherpartsofpath` :

```
 ajax: {
        url: 'http://' + window.location.hostname + '/otherpartsofpath', 
        type: 'GET',
        ...
```

But when rendered on the local computer it gives an error. That's why in this case I should define the URL explicitly:

```
 ajax: {
        url: 'http://localhost:10930/otherpartsofpath', 
        type: 'GET',
        ...
```

How could I make the code to work locally without explicitly defined URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a relative path `/test` will always result in the correct protocol, hostname and port. Thus, for convenience you could just always use:

```
 ajax: {
        url: '/otherpartsofpath', 
        type: 'GET',
        ...
```

When run on `http://test.com/directory/test.html` it is 
`http://test.com/otherpartsofpath`.

When run on `http://localhost:1234/directory/test.html` it is 
`http://localhost:1234/otherpartsofpath`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't [for security reasons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

Use a local server for testing. Set up a [proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) if you want to fetch data from a remote server.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not on port 80 locally you'll have to do something like

```
var hostName = window.location.hostname;
if ( window.location.port != '') {
    hostName += ':' + window.location.port;
}
```

and use that in your AJAX URL.